# Tracing objects that SHOULD be collected for logic purposes

Tags: .net, garbage-collection, weak-references

1. I have dictionary populated with WeakReferences.
2. Web service A: creates objects and places then on the weak-reference dictionary. (1)
3. Web service A sometimes keeps objects with strong referene, and sometimes it doesn't.

My problem:

I cannot trace objects that SHOULD be removed from the weak-reference dictionary because the garbage collector will not collect them immediately, it's collected only after a random and unpredictable amount of time.

The behavior is not consistent, for example

Example 1: Works as expected, variable ex1 is immediately collected.

```
Sub Example1(id as integer)
Dim ex1 as new Object
dim t as new WeakReference With {.target = ex1};
WeakReferenceDictionary.add(id,ex1)
End Sub<br>
```

Example2 'This doesn't work, ext1 is not imeediately collected

```
Sub Example1(id as integer)
  Dim ex1 as new Object
  dim t as new WeakReference With {.target = ex1};
  WeakReferenceDictionary.add(id,ex1)

  otherclass.refObject = ex1
  otherclass.refObject = Nothing

End Sub<br>
```

I have tried.
Placing the WeakDictionary inside Module1 (is a console application).
GC.Collect
GC.Collect(0)
GC.Collect(1)
GC.Collect(2)

My question. 
Is there anyway to Really force a garbage collection even If it will reduce performance on my application. I know I should not be using the GC for logic purposes, but for my solution is really convenient to do it this way.

Comment: Of course it does... I am not a fan of this solution myself, but I just need to keep track of these objects when they're no logner referenced by any of the application. Implementing reference counters in all of the app would be a huge amount of effort, and it will definetely be way more simple, elegant and reliable to use the garbage collection algorithm. I just want to know if there is a way of really forcing it, instead of just a suggestion to the GC.

Answer (score 2):

I'll start this post with a disclaimer: I am very skeptical that you have chosen the right approach by relying on garbage collection internals because the are not guaranteed, unpredictable and even if tested to work now, your code might break with any .NET patch release.

There are multiple reasons your object might not have been collected:

1. You are running under the debugger or have built in Debug mode. This will extend the object lifetimes a bit (the JIT does not eagerly mark variable contents as unused so that you can debug variables even if they went out of scope).
2. You place the GC.Collect calls at the wrong place
3. You did not call WaitForPendingFinalizers although your object has one

Maybe there are other reasons as well.

So how to fix this? Don't rely on GC. Rely on deterministic actions like implementing and calling Dispose or switching to a reference counting technique.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply, I have tested it in Release Mode, even outside of VisualStudio, the behavior continues. The WaitForPendingFinalizers method is not working for me because it would stop the thread (wich must be able to run concurrently).

As for implementation poupuses I have logic on the Finalize Method of these objects, but they're not called when they're supposed to. 

AS for your disclaimer, I totally agree with you. I Should not be messing with the GC. But we are unable to find a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

With thanks to  exacerbatedexpert; 
And reading the article www.sellsbrothers.com/writing/refcount_rotor.doc, found out that really forcing a GC that ensures that all objects that shuould be disposed will in fact be disposed in a predictable manner is not practical.

A referential counter (as shown on the article) must be implemented.

Another solution I found, is creating an array of all the objects of a particular class that have been created and then perform a second look trough Reflection using the root node, then compare the two and find who's missig. This approach would ensure to have a clean an consisten result but would consume too much resources having to do a full root-child scan.

Thank you both for your answers.

Comment: Here's another interesting article by microsoft.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163316.aspx